# Most appropriate tests for online advertising significance data

Tags: binomial-distribution, p-value, z-test

We are running ads and want to construct two Excel formulas, one calculating the p-value for every other ad vs the one with the highest CTR (click through rate) and another that compares the CPA to the one with the lowest CPA (cost per acquisition). The first item is binomial, the second formula would not be.

With no background in statistics, I am a bit overwhelmed trying to figure out which test to use. I have many online tools to use, but I need a formula I can implement in Excel - something that works in batch. What formula should I use for these two tasks?

Comment: Sorry about that! CPC stands for cost per click. I'm glad you caught that actually because I meant CTR (click through rate). My question is mathematically what do I need to do? I know how to make the mathematical formula into an excel function, I just don't know what statistical test to use (exact binomial, chi squared, etc.) My issue statistically is this: I have a binomial quantity (CTR which is a percentage) that is clicks/impressions. How do I get a p-value for comparing two of these CTR numbers? How would I do it if the stat was not binomial?

Comment: +1 Thanks for editing; your question is better for it. I made some minor changes myself to reflect your comment, please check that your intended question is still correctly conveyed.

Comment: Yes those edits are what I was trying to convey. Thank you!